# httpd ldap and file authentication error

Tags: ldap, svn, httpd

We have SVN running via Apache httpd. For authentication we use Active Directory and if the user isn't in AD, we fallback to file authentication. This works fine, except for the error messages in case of file authentication. The error message we get over and over again:

`auth_ldap authenticate: user <user> authentication failed; URI /svn/some/uri [User not found][No such object]`

We would like to filter out these messages since our log files grows rapidly due to this unnecessary log message.

Comment: I can't personally condone filtering out authentication failures. If this is on a local network and truly is generating that much spam, then there is a misbehaving process that needs to be dealt with. If this is internet facing, forwarding directly to AD without middleware is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question, but I have implemented a solution that I wanted to share wit you since you were helping me out and it may be of value to others.

Basically its rather simple, I didn't change the logging at all, I just changed the log rotation (/etc/logrotate.d/httpd) to:

```
/var/log/httpd/*log {
        compress
        compresscmd /usr/bin/bzip2
        compressext .bz2
        daily
        dateext
        maxage 31
        rotate 14
        size=+4096k
        notifempty
        missingok
        sharedscripts
        prerotate
                /bin/sed -i '/User not found/d' /var/log/httpd/*svn_error_log
        endscript
        postrotate
                /sbin/service httpd graceful > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
        endscript
}
```

This way all false positives are removed from the log file on a daily basis. The size of the log files is reduced and doesn't grow over time, since the files are removed after 31 days (max).

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the intent is to filter these logs to a *different* file, there are a few ways to go about it.

1. Send the `ErrorLog` to [syslog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errorlog) and log to different files based on the input.
2. Use [pipe syntax](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html#piped) to send the logs to a dedicated helper program, and use it to split the authentication failures off into a separate file. It's recommended to use a dedicated binary in conjunction with this directive in production (not a shell script) as it's performance sensitive.

Turning down [LogLevel verbosity](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#loglevel) is probably a bad idea because it effects other messages within the VirtualHost. Same with [LDAPLibraryDebug](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ldap.html#ldaplibrarydebug), and I think those messages are coming from Apache and not the LDAP library anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable error log messages at all. Something like

ErrorLog /dev/null

Comment: Recommending that someone turn off their `ErrorLog` entirely does not answer the question. (and a bad idea in production environments)

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to filter such messages. Only all messages at once

Comment: Hi,I Agree that turning the logging off isn't what we want. I only want to exclude the warnings about users not authenticated against AD, since this is in a way a false positive.